# Pass the output of SQL Connector to Custom Api App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which is triggered manually. The first connector is SQL connector which executes a stored proc and retrieves the data (json array). Now I want to pass this as an input to my custom api app. Below is the snap shot of my custom api method signature

[image: Figure 1]

After I add my custom api app I get the below screen. How do I pass the output of my SQL connector as an input to my API app?

[image: Figure 2]

Additionally I am confused as to why is the UI displaying me individual properties of my `Customer` class. Isn't it supposed to give me one big box to provide the json array input? I also tried entering static values in the input fields but then the option to save the logic app gets grayed out. I tried assigning the value `@body('Execute_stored_procedure')['ResultSets']['Table1']` to the body property of the api app in the code view and even after saving it successfully the value is reset to null when I load the designer again.

Below is the sample response from the SQL connector stored proc

```
{
    "body": {
        "OutputParameters": {},
        "ReturnCode": 0,
        "ResultSets": {
          "Table1": [
            {
                "FirstName": "Karen",
                "LastName": "Choi",
                "EmailAddress": null,
                "PhoneNumber": null,
                "PostalCode": "98104",
                "City": "Seattle",
                "Address": "Hidden",
                "StateCode": "Washington"
            },
            {
                "FirstName": "Jeanne",
                "LastName": "Blake",
                "EmailAddress": null,
                "PhoneNumber": null,
                "PostalCode": "90012",
                "City": "Los Angeles",
                "Address": "Hidden",
                "StateCode": "California"
            }
        ]
}
```

**PS**: I am using the new version of the logic apps. My custom API app used to work perfectly with the old version of the logic app.

**EDIT**

The logic app prevents me to save if I enter the static values on the UI. In the below image the *Save* option is disabled

[image: Figure 3]

**EDIT 2**

I found a strange behaviour. If I add a condition to the output of SQL connector I can see all the output properties of the SQL Connector.

[image: Figure 4]

Why is it that I can't see the same set of properties when I add my custom connector (Figure 2)?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use @body('ResultSets').Table1 instead in the code view ?

Comment: It failed to save the logic app with the error `Operation failed: A dependency references an action (ResultSets) that doesn't exist`. The name of the SQL stored proc action is `Execute_stored_procedure`.

Comment: 'ResultsSets doesn't look like an array could you try using .ResultsSets.Table1 instead of [ResultsSets][Table1] ? Also, here is the new official doc of the Defintion Language https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt643789.aspx

Comment: I will it check and let you know how it goes. The result set is an object. Table1 is the actual array.

Comment: Hi. I tried other combinations and even if it allows me to save it there is no effect and the moment I reload the logic app the input property is set to null automatically. If I enter static values in the fields then the save option gets disabled. Any more ideas which can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

@body('theSQLConnectorName').OutputParameters.result (alt. .ResultSet)

?

Comment: No luck with that either. I can't even add static values and save :(